# Minecraft custom launcher - forge mod load

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a launcher for minecraft.

When I launch it from workspace (in C:/users/hugo/workspace), everything work perfectly.

But when I run the launcher from desktop, it try to load mods from ALL folders in the desktop. It create a "logs" folder in the desktop folder too.

my launch command (without library load and after generation):

```
javaw -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M 
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Roaming\Survival-Machines\game1\natives
-cp "C:\Users\Hugo\AppData...versions\1.7.10\1.7.10.jar;"
net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch
--tweakClass cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
--username Slaynash
--version 1.7.10
--gameDir C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Roaming\Survival-Machines\game1\
--assetsDir C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Roaming\Survival-Machines\game1\assets
--assetIndex 1.7.10
--uuid 32********a3
--userProperties {}
--accessToken fa********cc
```

I launch it with java and function Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String cmd);

Is my launch command bad, or have i forgot an argument ?

Thanks for help,
Hugo

and sorry for my bad english :/

Comment: Sounds like you are using a relative path somewhere. Can you show us your Java code?

Comment: Go seek for help at http://www.minecraftforge.net/, they will defenitly give you precise info there.

Comment: I can't show you the java code now, i'm not on my computer. But if you have a decompiler you can get it at http://smlls.ddns.net/launcher/gamesFiles/minecraft_ctp3/mclauncher.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's in the launch command - I suggest you use a different override of the `exec()` method - one that allows you to set the working folder.

Your current one just inherits the current working directory, evidently the desktop.

Instead, use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String cmd, String[] argp, File dir);`

This lets you tell java where to start the application, which will presumably be the folder that contains your mods.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna try this tomorrow (i'm in France).

Comment: It works. But where I set my Xmx, Xms and maxPermsize arguments ? In the cmd or in the argp argument ?

Comment: They go in the cmd component just like you currently do.  The envp part is for environment variables (like JAVA_HOME) if you need any custom variables.  Otherwise you can just use `String [] envp = new String [0];`

Comment: Ok, it's what I did. I now have a new problem with the -Djava.libray.path argument, if you can help me :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934495/java-java-library-path-not-working-without-promp?noredirect=1#comment57602024_34934495