# Java - java.library.path not working without promp

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program, who use the following command to launch another jar:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String cmd, String[] argp, File dir);
```

The problem is when I try launch the Launcher with cmd.exe, it work,
but when I try to launch it without, the launcher launch the file and the file crash :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path)
```

The library argument (in the cmd line, not argp array):

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Roaming\Survival-Machines\game1\natives
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks, Hugo

(Sorry for my bad english :/)

EDIT:

the library is done like this:

natives
|lwjgl64.dll
|...
|twitchsdk.dll

Comment: the full launch code can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888160/minecraft-custom-launcher-forge-mod-load/34888536

Comment: yes, you are right (but it load file wrongly, due to minecraft bugs)

Comment: not working, and with the cmd too now (using -Djava.library.path='C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Roaming\Survival-Machines\game1\natives')

Comment: What does 'without prom' mean?

Comment: Try passing `PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Roaming\Survival-Machines\game1\natives` as one of `argp` parameter since on windows, native dll need to be available on PATH.

Comment: argp is an empty string, and dit is the file who the jar is located. For "'without prop", I mean " without lauching it with cmd)

Answer (score 1):

A bit rusty here, but dont you have to do something like this:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Roaming\Survival-Machines\game1\natives -jar <ApplicationJar-Name>
```

So it knows where to link the native library to?

Edit: Im not entirely sure if you have to give the exact path to each library you want to use (so the path [...]`\natives` could be wrong and should be [...]`\natives\<libraryName>`

Comment: the full launch code can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888160/minecraft-custom-launcher-forge-mod-load/34888536